# How to style a echo function with multiple variables

Tags: php, html, echo

I would like my code to display two variables on the same echo function, however, I want them to style them differently. Making the 'id' smaller and a different color. I do not know how to separate the two variables so I can add some code in-between.

I tried to use a second echo function, but then the 'id' displays at the bottom, separate from the 'quote' function.

```
echo "<p class='dash'>---------</p>","<p class='center' style='color:white' align='center'>" .$row['quote'] .$row['id'];
```

The  output will just display like this (bold text for output): 
**--------
 "This is the quote variable"1**

 However, I need is displayed like this:
**-------
"This is the quote variable"
1**


So basically what is needed is some way to add style to the second one. (I already styled the first one)

Comment: this perhaps: `echo "<p class='dash'>---------</p>","<p class='center' style='color:white' align='center'>" .$row['quote'] ."<br>".$row['id'];`

Comment: @tim I tried this earlier, but forgot the "" and couldn't figure out why it didn't work. Thank you for saving me the time!

Comment: Use the PHP concatenation operator. used to combine two string values to create one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way which eliminates use of dot concatenation operator:

```
<?php
$row["quote"] = "This is the quote";
$row["id"] = 1;
$p = [];
$p[0] = "<p class='dash'>---------</p>\n";
$p[1] = "<p class='center' style='color:white' align='center'>$row[quote]<br>\n$row[id]</p>\n";
echo $p[0],$p[1];
```

live [code here](https://3v4l.org/rCp3p)

Example HTML implementation:

```css
.dash {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.center {
  text-algin: center font-weight:900;
}

body {
background:navy
}
```

```html
<p class='dash'>---------</p>
<p class='center' style='color:white' align='center'>This is the quote<br> 1
</p>
```